# Need Awk or Unix Script to transpose / pivot in the following pattern

Tags: text-processing, awk

The file contains data in the following format (the first line is the header):

```
N ; A ; B 
=========
1 ; 01;02 
2; 02;02
```

Based on the 1st column, I expect the following output: N column remains the same, however the others can grow it can be C,D,E etc and the corresponding values can be captured.

```
1;A;01 
2;A;02
1:B;02
2;B;02
```

How can I do this?

Comment: extend your input according to *however the others can grow it can be C,D,E* to cover extended cases

Answer (score 0):

Here is a code snippet using Python...

#### Code:

```
# read in the data
with open('data_file', 'rU') as f:
    # read in the header
    header = [x.strip() for x in f.readline().split(';')]

    # drop the ======
    dump_marker = f.readline()

    # get the rest of the data
    data = [[x.strip() for x in line.split(';')] for line in f.readlines()]

# print the data in new format
for i, col in enumerate(header[1:]):
    for line in data:
        print("{};{};{}".format(line[0], col, line[i+1]))
```

#### data_file:

```
N ; A ; B
=========
1 ; 01;02
2 ; 02;02
```

#### Result:

```
1;A;01
2;A;02
1;B;02
2;B;02
```

Answer (score 0):

In bash it can be done with internal commands, `tail` and `cut`:

```bsh
#! /bin/bash
# Get header line
header=$( head -n 1 data_file )
# Make a variable with all delimiters (2)
delimiters=${header//[^;]/}
# Make an array with all column names
declare -a colnames=( ${header//;/ } )
# For all columns one at the time...
for C in $(seq 2 $((${#delimiters}+1)) ) ; do
    index=$((C-1))
    # Skip first 3 lines of data_file
    tail --lines=+3 data_file | cut -d\; -f1,$C | while read; do
        # Replace first ';' with column name
        line=${REPLY/;/;${colnames[$index]};}
        # Remove all spaces and print
        echo ${line// /}
    done
done
```

Explanation:

Get the first line of the file into a variable (which then can be modified)

```
header=$( head -n 1 data_file )
```

Remove all characters from the variable expect the cemi-colon delimiter

```
delimiters=${header//[^;]/}
```

Now the variable $delimiters contains ';;'

Replace all ';' with spaces. It will give "N   A   B". One or more spaces is the array delimiter:

```
declare -a colnames=( ${header//;/ } )
```

Get the number of characters in a variable:

```
${#delimiters}
```

Add one:

```
$((${#delimiters}+1))
```

Then

```
$(seq 2 $((${#delimiters}+1)) )
```

is equal to:

```
$(seq 2 3 )
```

Index in variable goes from 0..n, then -1 to look up column names:

```
index=$((C-1))
```

Read the file, skip first 3 lines, show only column number `$C`, read line into variable `$REPLY`:

```
tail --lines=+3 data_file | cut -d\; -f1,$C | while read; do
```

Answer (score 0):

And a solution using `awk`:

```
awk -F';' '{ gsub(/ /,"");}
           NR==1 { cols = split($0, col); }
           NR > 2 { for (i = 2; i <= cols; i++) {
                        data[col[i]";"$1] = $1";"col[i]";"$i; }
                  }
           END { no = asorti(data, sorted);
                 for (i = 1; i <= no; i++) {
                     print data[sorted[i]]; }
               }' input
```